# Is there an Object Cache library available for SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, caching, orm, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm working on a new project written in Python with Flask & SQLAlchemy. The latter seems like a decent ORM but doesn't seem to consider caching as its responsibility.

It provides some examples on how to leverage dogpile.cache @ http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/examples.html#module-examples.dogpile_caching but this seems to offer no more than basic query results caching which is really only valuable for read-only models.

What I am looking for is a real Level 2 Object Cache integrated into the ORM which store each object via its PK and ensures identity in a concurrently shared cache. I have experience with multiple caching libraries working with Java ORMs but I'm not able to find anything for SQLAlchemy. Does no such thing exist for Python yet?

Comment: maybe you should look rather at WSGI container level? AFAIK it has decent plugins for memcache and REDIS.

Comment: That is useful if you want to implement your own caching strategy, but ORM L2 cache is a fairly complex thing I normally rely on a library for...